# How to Format a date in flutter without any seperators?

Tags: flutter

I have tried to format date using seperators Using intl packags but how should I format date like 20201227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: `DateFormat('yyyyMMdd').format(date)`

### Printscreen of the result:

[image]

Comment: Strange - I updated my answer with a printscreen. What does your code look like? Are you getting any errors?